# Unwanted error in Cython code in calling the functions of c

Tags: python, cython

I am a beginner in Cython and I am following the official documentation of Cython and in that there is a section called "Calling C functions" and in that it is written that how to import c function in .py(python file, as according to the 'Pure Python' section of that page) there is code in 'Pure Python' section when I copied it and run on my code editior 'VS code'. So it show me error that is

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cython.cimports'; 'cython' is not a package`

the code which is officially published on the page of documentation of Cython website is here:

```
from cython.cimports.libc.stdlib import atoi
@cython.cfunc
def parse_charptr_to_py_int(s: cython.p_char):
    assert s is not cython.NULL, "byte string value is NULL"
    return atoi(s)  # note: atoi() has no error detection!
```

Now, I can't able to understand the problem that why it is occuring when I am following the official documentation of Cython
`Note`:- I was already Installed the Cython using `pip install cython`.

the code which I was written in my editior is as follows:

```
import cython
from cython.cimports.libc.stdlib import atoi
@cython.cfunc
def parse_charptr_to_py_int(s: cython.p_char):
    assert s is not cython.NULL, "byte string value is NULL"
    return atoi(s)  # note: atoi() has no error detection!

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result= parse_charptr_to_py_int("Rahul")
    print(result)
```

So, if you know that why the error is occuring and what kind of mistake I has done so please let me know also. it will help me a lot in understanding the concepts of Cython much clear and  it will help to understand that how to implement it, please!, if you solve this i will very grateful to you!! Thank You!!

Comment: What is parse_string?

Comment: @paxdiablo, I am  really sorry for that mistake, that is the name of the function of cython .cfunc called "parse_charptr_to_py_int".

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of possible issues:

- The pure Python mode cimport is only available on the Cython 3 alpha build. You've probably installed the older Cython 0.29.x. If you don't want to use the Cython 3 alpha then you can switch the documentation back to the earlier version: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html
- You need to compile Cython for it to work ("pure Python mode doesn't change that. It just avoids non-Python syntax). See https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html. Note that [the documentation for cimports says](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/pure.html#cimports)

  > Note that this does not mean that C libraries become available to Python code. It only means that you can tell Cython what cimports you want to use, without requiring special syntax.